# LinkedIn Share Button posts form incorrectly

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to display a LinkedIn Share Button on a webpage but if the button is in a  tag then the form is posted and that's not I think what is intended. I know moving the button outside the FORM will fix this but I don't have control over the placing of the button. The reason I believe is that the button created by the LinkedIn code does not have the type set as 'type="button"' so defaults to type="submit".

```
<form action="anotherpage.htm">
<script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-url="https://www.linkedin.com"></script>
</form>
```

This is the default LinkedIn button from their help site. I would expect on clicking the button for the linkedin share window to pop-up but the underlying page to stay where it is. Actually the underlying page "posts" to the form action of "anotherpage.htm".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rely on the LinkedIn Share Button API SDK and JS Bundle to have a share button.  All you really ought to need is...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Then you can just make any button, using any HTML, CSS, or JavaScript that you like, and hyperlink it to allow sharing of a page.

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

Unfortunately, it seems that you have no other choice than this parameter to share: `url`.

If you are interested in a regularly maintained github project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]